# Как получить доступ более чем к одной подстроке, найденной smatch()

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
string s1 = "20.02.1912 and 02.08.1756."
```

И есть шаблон:

```
regex date_pat1{ R"((\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4}))" };
```

Нужно иметь доступ и к первой дате (подстроке), и второй дате, и n-ой дате, если такая есть в строке.
Как это можно сделать, если regex_search() находит только первую подстроку, соответствующую данному шаблону?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `std::sregex_iterator`, а все найденные даты поместите в `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::regex date_pat1{ R"(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})" };
    std::string s = "20.02.1912 and 02.08.1756.";
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), date_pat1);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        res.push_back(m.str());
    }
    // Демо
    for (auto i: res) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

См. [онлайн-демо](https://ideone.com/gbks7N).

Результат:

```
20.02.1912
02.08.1756
```