# Почему std::regex_search всегда возвращает только одно вхождение?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, c++17, std-regex

Пробую регулярки из `std::regex`. Никак не получается получить все вхождения `"[Hh][aeo]h[aeo]"` в строке `" hehe Haha hoho huhu"`. Почему в приведённом ниже коде `std::regex_search` всегда возвращает `reg_match` размером 1?

```
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
int main() {
    std::regex r ("[Hh][aeo]h[aeo]");
    string str{ " hehe Haha hoho huhu" };
    std::smatch reg_match;
    cout << std::regex_search(str, reg_match, r) << endl;
    cout << reg_match.size() << endl;
    for (auto& c : reg_match) cout << "| " << c.str() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить доступ более чем к одной подстроке, найденной smatch()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-smatch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы останавливаете поиск после нахождения первого вхождения. А `reg_match.size()` делает не то, что вы думаете, что оно делает. Возвращаемое значение - это количество подходящих *подвыражений* в этом подходящем выражении + 1, соответственно итерация по `reg_match` начинает с подходящего выражения и продолжается для каждого подвыражения.

Вместо этого стоило продолжать искать вхождения до упора:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    std::regex r ("[Hh][aeo]h[aeo]");
    string str{ " hehe Haha hoho huhu" };
    std::smatch reg_match{};
    auto begin{str.cbegin()};
    auto end{str.cend()};
    while(std::regex_search(begin, end, reg_match, r))
    {
        cout << reg_match.size() << endl;
        for (auto& c : reg_match) cout << "| " << c.str() << endl;
        // следующую итерацию поиска начинаем с позиции сразу после начала подошедшего выражения
        begin += reg_match.position() + 1;
    }
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pLwRHmCnu5cpYsVe)

Comment: Большое спасибо что пояснили.

Comment: А почему std::regex_search принимает только константные итераторы? Что мешает принять ему обычные?

Comment: @mrFieldy Вообще-то ничего не мешает, однако тогда бы пришлось использовать `std::match_results<std::string::iterator>` вместо `smatch` (который является алиасом для `std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`)

Comment: понятно, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать sregex_token_iterator():

```
string var = "first second third forth";

regex wsaq_re("\\s+"); 
copy( sregex_token_iterator(var.begin(), var.end(), wsaq_re, -1),
    sregex_token_iterator(),
    ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

Либо просто итерировать вашу строку пока regex_search, например:

```
{
    regex exp("(\\b\\S*\\b)");
    smatch res;
    string str = "first second third forth";

    string::const_iterator searchStart( str.cbegin() );
    while ( regex_search( searchStart, str.cend(), res, exp ) )
    {
        cout << ( searchStart == str.cbegin() ? "" : " " ) << res[0];
        searchStart += res.position() + res.length();
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```