# Не работает OR в регулярном выражении

Tags: c++, c, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Помогите найти ошибку. Ищу вхождения log, lg, ln в строке. Вот код:

```
int main() {
    string input;
    cout << "Enter string to calculate: ";
    cin >> input;

    cmatch logElements;
    regex logRegex("log|ln|lg");
    if (regex_search(input.c_str(), logElements, logRegex)){
        for (int i = 0; i < logElements.size(); i++){
            cout << logElements[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ввожу строку lg13+log15+ln15. В консоль выводится только первое совпадение lg. Почему так не пойму. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то `regex_search` одну подстроку и должен искать. Для поиска нескольких вхождений используется: `regex_match`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить доступ более чем к одной подстроке, найденной smatch()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-smatch)

Answer (score 1):

> В консоль выводится только первое совпадение lg. Почему так не пойму.

Потому что `regex_search ()` ищет только первое совпадение, а в массиве возвращает по одному совпадению для каждой группы символов (выражения в скобках). Чтобы искать все совпадения можно воспользоваться, например `std::sregex_iterator`:

```
std::string input;
// ...
std::regex logRegex{"log|ln|lg"};

std::sregex_iterator rxIt{s.begin(), s.end(), logRegex};
std::sregex_iterator rxIt_end;
for (rxIt; rxIt!=rxIt_end; ++rxIt) {
  std::cout << rxIt->str() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас на самом деле выражение такое:

```
lo____g
```

или

```
l_____n
```

или

```
l____g
```

а не 3 разных слова, как вы думаете. Чтобы сделать 3 разных слова, надо объединить их в группы.

Comment: а как реализовать регулярное выражение, чтобы искало 3 разных слова? В питоне такое выражение работало, в с++ видимо по другому нужно прописать.

Comment: Я же написал - объединить в группы: (log)|(ln)|(lg)

Comment: Т.е. вы предполагаете, что регулярное выражение автора вопроса будет работать так: `lo(g|l)(n|l)g`? Тогда каким образом это выражение смогло найти "lg"?

Comment: Не работает. Объединил в группы, на выходе для того же выражения получил lg  lg

Comment: @АндрейРафальский покажите полный текст программы, например, тут https://ideone.com

Comment: https://ideone.com/OXlOW3

Comment: @АндрейРафальский ну, всё верно находит только первое совпадение

Comment: @АндрейРафальский чтобы найти всю строку, нужно использовать итератор