# Реализация вычисления выражения с логарифмическими функциями

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такую задачу. В программировании новичок, не знаю с чего начать. С консоли вводится строка, которая является математическим выражением с логарифмическими функциями(ln, lg, log). Необходимо проанализировать строку и подсчитать количество использованных в выражении логарифмов, рассчитать их значение, и вывести на экран строку с подставленными у него значений логарифмов. Подскажите, как это реализовать, хочу использовать С/С++. Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Начать можно с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/918103/Не-работает-or-в-регулярном-выражении)

Comment: Аргументами логарифмов могут быть только числа (`log(12.3)`) или выражения тоже (`log((100 + 23) / 10)`)?

Comment: аргументами могут быть только числа

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас наверное заминусят.

Вот алгоритм.

1) получить выражение

2) понять какой логарифм

3) вычислить

4) вывести

Допустим на ввод пошла такая **строка** `ln(K)` в С++ соответсвует `log(K)`

Во первых нам необходимо её распарсить, тобишь понять что там происходит.
 у нас есть 3 случая:

ln(c) - натуральный логарифм . в С++ log()

lg(c)- десятичный логарифм  . в С++ log10()

log(a,b) - вычисление логарифма с основанием а  от b.
 В С++ нет такой функции, так что можна написать свою через разложение в ряд Фурье

Следовательно( псевдокод)

```
if(string contains  substring "ln(" )
{
   сout << log(a);
}
```

c другими аналогично.

**Примечание:** Распарсить нам надо строку на 2 части `ln(` и то число `K` логарифм которого нам необходимо получить.

Comment: *"можна написать свою через разложение в ряд Фурье"* Можна проще: `log(a) / log(b)` = логарифм `a` по основанию `b`.