# Не работает регулярное выражение C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Почему `std::regex_search()` выдаёт мне только одно совпадение, хотя на сайте https://regex101.com/ такое-же регулярное выражение находит 5 совпадений.
Код:

```
int main()
{

    std::smatch result;
    std::regex regular("[a-zA-Z]\\w*");
    std::string str("var1 var2_ va3r  v 4var");
    std::cout << std::regex_search(str, result, regular)<<std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/i99dro/1/ ссылка на эту регулярку.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-smatch не то?

Comment: Всё, теперь разобрался, спасибо большое.